# OpenAI embeddings disappears when passed to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, embedding, llama-index

I have the weirdest problem I've encountered so far. This piece of code works perfectly:

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:xxx", api_key="xxx")
response = client.embeddings.create(input=["Your string here"], model="Azure-Text-Embedding-ada-002")
embedding_vector = response.data[0].embedding
```

however, if I try to pass client through a class, like this:

```
class CustomEmbedding:
    def __init__(self, client, model="Azure-Text-Embedding-ada-002"):
        self.client = client
        self.model = model

    def embed(self, texts):
        response = self.client.embeddings.create(input=texts, model=self.model)
        return [r.embedding for r in response.data]
    [...]

client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:xxx", api_key="xxx")
embed_model = CustomEmbedding(client, model="Azure-Text-Embedding-ada-002")
```

I get that :

```
AttributeError: 'OpenAI' object has no attribute 'embeddings'
```

And I checked. self.client really does not have an embeddings attribute inside the class ,but it does have it outside of it.  I literally have no clue what is going on.